# Tools for a good web development environment on Chrome OS

Tags: google-chrome, web-applications, google-chrome-os

What webapps / tools would you recommend for a productive frontend web dev workflow on Chrome OS?

I currently use [Sublime Text 2](http://www.sublimetext.com/) with [LiveReload](http://livereload.com/) on my Windows PC.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have today a lot of options. Here are just a few:

- **Cloud9**, an IDE for JavaScript, Python, PHP, and Ruby. Cloud9 uses the HTML5 FileSystem capability and AppCache to sync files, so you can even code offline.
- **Neutron Drive** seems like a good option with a close integration with Google drive and lots of languages its support.
- **ShiftEdit** - which give you many options to develop in your language: PHP, Ruby, HTML, CSS and JavaScript and then by using (S)FTP you can save your work to  Dropbox or Google Drive.
- **Kodingen** is another IDE that includs: Code Editor, Cloud Hosting, Database Administration and collaboration
- **Codey** - Easy to use code editor for HTML, PHP, CSS, JS.
- **Akshell** - Server-side JavaScript development and hosting platform. They got some git integration built in their IDE.
- **eXo Cloud IDE** - an IDE that support: HTML/CSS/JS and PHP/JAVA/RUBY and many more options.

For more, here is an '[old' post](http://greenido.wordpress.com/2011/07/04/web-developers-and-the-new-chromebook/) I wrote on this topic when the first Chromebook was launched.

Comment: Thanks I'm gonna try Neutron Drive.

Answer (score 1):

- **CodeAnyWhere** a code editor in a browser with an integrated ftp client, and all popular web formats are supported (HTML, PHP, JavaScript, CSS, and XML).

Answer (score 1):

**goormIDE** - an opensource IDE based on node.js for JavaScript, Python, PHP, JSP, C/C++, JAVA, Ruby, Go, Dart, and so on. it provides beta-version in opensource via github.com and beta-service on goorm.io, now. if you want this, just type 'npm install goorm -g' for your local machine.

Answer (score 1):

Check out [Caret](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/caret/fljalecfjciodhpcledpamjachpmelml) if you like Sublime Text. It's a packaged app, no connection required.